# How to setup a RAID Install with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, installation, raid

I have one pc that has two 120GB hard drives in it. There is currently no operating system installed in my PC. I want to install Ubuntu so it will see and use both hard drives for booting and storage as though they were one. I have looked through the FAQ & blogs and the only one that gets close is the Raid setup, however this version of Ubuntu does not list raid as an option.

I only want Ubuntu on these hard drives, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an Alternate 12.04.1 ISO for RAID setup - [32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso), [64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso).

For a complete walk-through, please see the [Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID).

Comment: The wiki page you link to says "This page is about Ubuntu 9.10".  Is it still relevant for 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

> use both hard drives for booting and storage as though they were one

To do so, you'll have to check on your computer if the RAID 0 is possible. The easiest way is to give your motherboard information.

FYI : RAID 0 will show only one logical partition as 240Gb but you won't have any backup partition. RAID 1 will show only 120Gb but with redundancy (if one of your HDD burns, your system will still work the time you change the failing HDD)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are installing the "Ubuntu Desktop" edition, it miss the RAID options.
I suggest to install the "Ubuntu Server" edition and follow the [Advanced Installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html).
Then you can update the Server edition to the Desktop edition run this:

```
# apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```